# Average below variable rows-VBA Excel Programming

Tags: vba, excel

There is a column of like 200 rows that contain integer data.How can I find the average of all these data in the rows and put the result in the same column in 201th row?

Comment: Just put '=AVERAGE(A1:A200)' in the 201th row or that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: @dubafek you didn't read the question carefully :p :p :p ... ok sorry... edited...

Comment: There are like 10 columns for which I have to calculate the average as mentioned above.I want a function/sub in VBA which does that for all such columns.

Comment: I don't understand what is the extra behavior that want using VBA. Can you explain I little bit more why using that formula it's not enough for your application?
By the way, functions in VBA are basically the same as using excel's formulas (not the subs of course)

Comment: @Dubafek I got what I was trying to do.Thanks :)

Comment: @dubafek- the 1st 8 words of the OP question should answer your question: "There is a column of like 200 rows"

Answer (score 0):

This will find your last row and your last column, then place the average 2 rows below it.

```
Sub GetAverage()
    Dim Rws As Long, Col As Integer, r As Range, FrNg As Range

    Set r = Range("A1")
    Rws = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=r, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Col = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=r, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set FrNg = Range(Cells(Rws + 2, 1), Cells(Rws + 2, Col))    ' range A2 to last cell on sheet

    FrNg = "=AVERAGE(A2:A" & Rws & ")"
    FrNg.Value = FrNg.Value

End Sub
```

See more one selection code.
[Selection Codes](http://www.xlorate.com/selection-codes.html)